# Add Matrices in a Specific Layout

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, addition

My professor wants me to print out the matrices side by side with the "+" between the two matrices and then a "=" sign. In the end he wants us to add the matrices together.

This is the work so far.

So the result would come out as:

```
1 2 3   9 8 7   10 10 10
4 5 6 + 6 5 4 = 10 10 10
7 8 9   3 2 1   10 10 10

enter code here public static void main(String[] args) {
    int matrix1[][] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{6,7,8}};
    int matrix2[][] = {{9,8,7},{6,5,4},{3,2,1}};
    int result1;
    int[][] result2 = new int[2][3];


    for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix1[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.printf(matrix1[i][j] + " ");
            System.out.print("");
        }
        System.out.println("");

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix2.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix2[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.printf(matrix2[i][j] + " ");

        }

    System.out.println("");



    }
}
```

My problem is, how could I print it side by side with the solutions?

Comment: Can you edit this such that it becomes a question?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the two printing loops for your matrices:

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix1[0].length; j++) {
        System.out.printf(matrix1[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

for (int i = 0; i < matrix2.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix2[0].length; j++) {
        System.out.printf(matrix2[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

They print matrix 1, then 2 - and so the matrices will be below each other.

If you want the matrices side by side, you need to print line 1 of every matrix, then - after a new line - line 2 of every matrix, etc. By re-arranging how the loops go through the matrices, you could have your new layout.

Comment: Thank you very much will try to figure it out!

Comment: When you do, come back to triumph :) - or if you're stuck after trying a few things, tell us what you've tried for another push.

Answer (score 0):

You unfortunately cannot print them one at a time, you need to take it row by row. This solution **requires** both matrix1 and matrix2 to be of equal height. But here's a template that should get you started.

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.length; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < matrix1[i].length; j++) {

  }

  if (i == matrix1/2) {

  } else {  //One part of if handles when "+" is needed, other one doesn't

  }

  for (int j = 0; j < matrix2[i].length; j++) {

  }

  if (i == matrix1/2) {

  }

  for (int j = 0; j < ???; j++) {

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. At least there's some light at the end of the tunnel